# Modifier Removes Morph Targets GLTF

Tags: three.js, blender, gltf, modifier

I want to export a GLTF file. I selected the apply modifier option on export to show my full mesh (I used a mirror modifier) but doing so removed all my morph targets. How do I export the file with the mirror modifier and keep all my targets?
blender 2.9

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because you should ask it on [blender.se]

Comment: I though I *was* on stackoverflow for Blender. Thanks for letting me know.